# Standalone offline web map tile server

Tags: web-mapping, wms

I am working on a web-map system which I am embedding in a form in an Access database. I will be distributing this database to clients so need it to be as self-contained as possible (i.e. no installation). Other than Access itself I am trying to keep this FOSS in order to keep development time and costs down.

I am looking for a way of serving map tiles to this without using an internet connection.

Can this be achieved by creating a well-structured folder of pre-created png tiles?

If not, is there a mapserver which I could distribute alongside my Access database?

Bonus question: What software can I use to create WMS tiles?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your tiles using GeoWebCache [GWC](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html) (and other tile caches I expect) and run the preseeding operation to create all the tiles on disk you can then copy those tiles to a remote machine and use the [OpenLayers XYZLayer](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ-js.html) to access the tiles.

Comment: XYZLayer sounds promising. I've been using Leaflet so far and it seems that it supports this too. What is GWC? I'm guessing not the Gambian Worker's Collective...

Comment: GeoWebCache - the GeoServer web cache system

Answer (score 0):

[MBTiles](http://mapbox.com/mbtiles-spec/) offers a nice, clean way to store tiles on your local file system, in a convention that is identical to how most tile servers work (row/col/level).

You don't say what type of client will actually be fetching the tiles (is it the form of your custom Access DB or some web client???).  Desktop apps should be very easy.  If it is a web client such as OpenLayers, a little work will be required to pull from the local sqlite db, but nothing that hasn't been done before.

Comment: I am using [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com), inside a Microsoft Web Browser control, in a form, in an Access database.

Comment: Here's a page explaining how to fire a method in VB from javascript in a hosted browser control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752045(VS.85).aspx.  Disclaimer:  This is definitely a hack.

Comment: Why would I need that?

Comment: to get tiles from sqlite db from web browser.